# External HDD Accessible in Ubuntu but not in Windows

Tags: external-hard-drive, multi-boot

I have 1 TB WD Elements External HDD which is detected on windows but can't be opened.But when running Ubuntu I have no problems in using the HDD.
It just doesn't open in windows.When I double click on the drive icon, it just keeps on loading but doesn't open.
Can anyone suggest a solution ???

Also it worked fine until a while ago in windows as well.

Comment: Which filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

If you format the drive to use an NTFS or FAT file system, both operating systems will be able to use it (chose NTFS for modern external drives).

If you first formatted it in Ubuntu, it is likely an EXT format, which Windows can't read. In this case, copy the data off the drive using Ubuntu, format to NTFS, and then put the data back on.

Comment: the HDD is in NTFS format. It worked fine in windows before but now it isn't working.